# Equation of 3D Parabola

Tags: analytic-geometry

Consider the horizontal alignment of the centerline of a road. The centerline is curved with a radius of $200$m on its plan view. The centerline also has a parabolic vertical alignment. This results in a parabola curved in space as it follows the horizontal alignment. Normally the relevant 2D equation for elevation "$Z$" would be $Z=Ax^2+Bx+C$

What is the relevant equation of this "curved" parabola?

Comment: Please use LaTeX

Comment: then  $x$ shall be replaced  $s=r \theta$, the length along the circle. Do you know cylindrical coordinates ?

Comment: I know what they are but have never used them, but thanks for the tip, I will look into the possibilities.